# Can you put resources in Jenkins Workflow Global Library

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I am trying out the Jenkins Workflow plugin (https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin) and using the Workflow Global Library (https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/tree/master/cps-global-lib) that comes with it.

I wanted to embed some script calls in my shared functions (bash/python). The obvious way to do this seems to be by using sh """...""". However this leads to some escaping being required ($ has to be escaped). Also its a bit messy to develop a script inside string quotes.

Is there a way to access resource files (e.g. a .sh or .py file) stored in the Global Library during a workflow execution?
So that I can do something like

```
sh getScript("script.sh")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'''` syntax might be more helpful, since it reduces the need to escape. There are other Groovy syntaxes that are even better for long blocks, with various tradeoffs on the escape character.

But yes it would be helpful to be able to reference a static resource in the “classpath”. Feel free to file an RFE for this.